# Search across multiple JSON documents using Redis Search

Tags: redis, node-redis

I've been researching this problem for some time now and I can't find a good practical example of how this is implemented.

Is this possible? and how would it be done practically and correctly, if it doesn't need to be hacked together

ty! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible. :)

This is precisely RediSearch's purpose.

Take a look at the [documentation here](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/indexing/).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the location in the document, but how do I search across multiple json documents stored under different keys?

Comment: Does it just do this by default, so when you create an index and use FT.CREATE and FT.SEARCH, it looks through every key with a value that contains a json path & value matching both?

Comment: After you have a RediSearch index that indexed your JSON keys, any FT.SEARCH will perform the search on these keys

Comment: Do you have to specify the keys ahead of time? I was hoping to create documents stored under N number of arbitrary but predictable key name patterns, and search across them.

Comment: All the documents would have the same shape, that I would need to search across

Comment: You should read about RediSearch. This is precisely its purpose.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as accepted, but please add that confirmation to your answer if you want :) ty! I didn't seem to understand how it works, but I also saw another answer in their forums that threw me off. https://forum.redis.com/t/search-between-multiple-documents/1431

Comment: I believe that the question was implying searching for results across multiple indexes. It is not very well formed.